# Getting data from an array and applying if condition

Tags: arrays, bash, if-statement

I am stuck here as i read data from a csv file and stored in an array
Now i want to display the data based on the condition

```
file_csv="ports.csv"
index=0
while IFS= read -r line;do
        array["$index"]="$line"
        index=$(($index + 1));
done < $file_csv

for lines in "${array[@]}"
do
        #echo $(awk '/down/ {print}' | sed -n 's/HUAWEI//' <<< $index )
        if [[ ${array[@]}=="down"  ]]; then
                echo  "found $index" | sed 's/Huawei/d/'
        fi

done

a=$(awk '/down/ {print}' $file_csv)
```

Output required

```
Interface down down Summary
```

Comment: What's the content of  the input file (ports.csv) ? What is the filtering condition ?

Answer (score 0):

To load the csv to an array efficiently:

```
 mapfile array < "$file_csv"
```

If what you are trying to do is store only lines with `down`:

```
array=( $( awk '/down/ {print}' "$file_csv" ) )
```

(Using the `awk` you already had, just wrapping another set of parens around it to make `a` an array.)

Your loop as written is broken in several ways:

```
for lines in "${array[@]}"           # iteratively assigns each element to $lines
do  if [[ ${array[@]}=="down"  ]]    # [1] tests "down" against the unquoted entire set
    then echo  "found $index" |      # [2] $index unset
           sed 's/Huawei/d/'         # Huawei not in "found $index"
    fi
done
```

1: Your `if` is unlikely to work, and may blow up your program syntactically, as the entire, unquoted content of the array is being presented for comparison to "down", which is probably not what you expect the entire array to contain...

2: "$index" hasn't been set at all.

Maybe this is closer to what you wanted? This filters out the Huawei records.

```
array=( $( awk '/down/ && !/Huawei/ {print}' "$file_csv" ) )
```

If you want that to be case-insensitive -

```
array=( $( awk 'BEGIN{ IGNORECASE = 1 }; /down/ && !/Huawei/ {print}' "$file_csv" ) )
```

Are you using the array later in the code for something else? 
Because if not, you'd do better to skip the array and just use the `awk`.

Can you elaborate?